# Combining an 'sort on edit', and a 'move row dependent on a specific value' on Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to combine two separate functions that I both have working independently, but I am lost with the world of 'onEdit' and similar things.

I have one script that sorts separate sheets based on a column specific to that sheet (this is important as it may need to change in future, and I need the ability to keep sorting the separate sheets by different columns). My other script moves (possibly 'cuts' is a better word to use?) a row to a different sheet, based on the value of a specific cell within the row, i.e. when A1 == X, all of row 1 moves to a different sheet within the same document, and then sorts the sheet that has had a row copied to it. So, what I want is to combine these two functions together, but as they are both onEdit functions, I am struggling. I have tried

```
function main() {
        script1();
        script2();
        script3();
    ]
```

but it is not working, as it seems to result in onlu the 'moverows' fuction working, regardless of which way round I call them.

Thank you for any help.

Thank you to Miguel Rivera Rios for pointing out my issue of trying to use two onEdit methods at once, I have used an installable trigger to get around this and it is working much better.

Comment: Are you able to share some of the real code that you used? There can only be one `onEdit` method at a time, and `onEdit` cannot be triggered by script executions, so you would just need to write the script with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 & e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    const osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart)
  }
}
```

Move's row whose checkbox is checked in column 1